# What does "the hypotheses ... are verified as null" mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validity

Context:

> This article examines the criterion-related validity of the results obtained by the application of four different methods of assessment to the correction of a second-year exam of
>   translation into the foreign language (Spanish-English) done by 64 university students.
>   These four methods are based on types currently used by university teachers, and the
>   validation study is based on 17 external criteria taken from six different sources. In spite
>   of this variety, a factor analysis reveals the presence of one main factor which is clearly
>   identifiable as Translation Competence. **The hypotheses regarding differences between the
>   validity of the methods are verified as null**, since all the systems, whether based on error
>   analysis or a holistic approach, prove to correlate significantly with this main factor [[Source](https://www.erudit.org/en/journals/meta/2001-v46-n2-meta159/004583ar/abstract/)]

What does the sentence in boldface mean?

Comment: I have never heard that before, but it sounds like they interpret a non-significant difference from the null-hypothesis as evidence *for* the null-hypothesis, which would be wrong.

Comment: Even worse - it appears that they claim $A=B=C=D$ based on the result that all $A,B,C,D$ are correlated to some $F$. And "holistic" is not exactly a technical term...

Comment: It is important for potential respondents to *read the paper,* because the "hypotheses" to which this abstract refers are not valid statistical hypotheses and were not correctly assessed in a null hypothesis testing framework.  The hypotheses are stated in Section 2.2 and the conclusions about them are summarized in Section 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited this, as what I said before was what I interpreted from the abstract. The rest of the analysis explains this better.

The three hypotheses that the bold line is referring to are verified by comparing the differences between the four methods. These hypotheses are not statistical hypotheses but exploratory hypotheses:

> 2.2. The three hypotheses
>
> (1) The first hypothesis was that “It is possible to improve the quality of methods of correction based on
> error analysis, if this analysis takes into account the possible
> effect of the errors on the rest of the translation.” To verify this
> hypothesis, the results obtained by Method A were compared to those
> obtained by Method B.
>
> (2) The second hypothesis was that “Methods of
> assessment based on error analysis are more reliable and valid than
> holistic methods.” To verify this hypothesis, the results obtained by
> Methods A and B were compared to those obtained by Method C.
>
> (3) The
> third hypothesis was that “The quality of a translation can be
> assessed more accurately if the method of assessment combines error
> analysis with a holistic appreciation.” To verify this hypothesis, the
> results obtained by Method A were compared to those obtained by Method
> D.

These 4 methods check the validity of student translations of an authentic text done under exam conditions. "Validity" is the outcome (result) of each method.

This study did not detect differences between the results obtained by these 4 methods, and hence none of the 3 hypotheses were verified. This is what the bold line is stating.

Comment: This is a reasonable guess, but it does not correspond to what is actually explained in the paper.

Comment: Good spot @whuber I've changed my response to better reflect the paper

Comment: What I found particularly interesting and important is that none of these is a valid, testable statistical hypothesis and the methods used to "verify" them appear to be exploratory rather than valid statistical testing methods.  Moreover, it is difficult to understand the bizarre phrase "verified as null" as meaning "were not verified."  The former affirms that sufficiently strong evidence was found for a "null" (whatever that might mean) whereas the latter merely says the evidence is not strong enough to support the hypotheses.

Comment: @whuber Is it possible that the bizzare phrase has been written due to language problems. This might be the case since the writer's mother tongue is most probably Spanish, not English. Mind you, I am sure an article published in such a journal would have certainly been checked language wise too.

Comment: @Juya Yes, at first I thought the quotation itself was a bad translation.  (The French version of the abstract doesn't read quite as badly.)  However, the language in the paper, although stilted, is clear enough, so I felt one couldn't blame the translator for this one.